# can't generate makefile in eclipse windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, makefile, eclipse-kepler

I have a c++ eclipse linux project that I want to port to windows as well. I opened the project from my git repo and opened a new build configuration for windows. When I didn't find the makefile generated by eclipse I opened the project properties->c/c++ build and look at the build setting tab, and saw that build type is "internal build" and I can't change that (grayed out). so how do I open import a project in windows and enable external builder in order to generate a makefile for windows?
using win7. MinGW. eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer - 
[eclipse ducomentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm) - on the tool chain change the "current builer" to make builder.